# How did Muhammed of Ghouri die?

Tags: ancient-india, afghanistan, mughals, indian

Indians believe that Prithviraj Chauhan killed The Muhammed of Ghouri, but according to history Muhammed of Ghouri died after the death of Prithviraj Chauhan. Prithviraj's tomb is disrespected in Afghanistan as the Afghas also believe that he killed their emperor. So what is the truth?

[The story](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.speakingtree.in/blog/even-to-this-day-afghans-stab-prithviraj-chauhans-grave-to-avenge-killing-of-muhammad-ghori/m-lite) which is believed about Muhammed of Ghouri's death.

Comment: <https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.speakingtree.in/blog/even-to-this-day-afghans-stab-prithviraj-chauhans-grave-to-avenge-killing-of-muhammad-ghori/m-lite>

Comment: The given link is not accessible from the UK.

Comment: This (sourced) Wikipedia article on [Mu'izz ad-Din Muhammad Ghori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_of_Ghor#Final_days_and_death) says *"His killers are unconfirmed. It may have been the Khokhars or Ismāʿīlīs. One source states that he was assassinated by the Nizari Ismaili Assassins."* It then adds *"In Indian folklore, the death of Mu'izz was caused by Prithviraj Chauhan, but this is not borne out by historical documents and Prithviraj died much earlier before the death of Mu'izz."* I seriously doubt we can do better than this.

Comment: I think the *actual* question is "How do I continue research when limited sources conflict?", but I'm not sure, and I think someone else could do better. I think this question fits a pattern that is a good fit for H:SE, but I'm having trouble phrasing it correctly. Anyone else have insight?